# Tile Layout not working with 100% width

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5

I have a list with tile layout,I have given the item renderer's width as 100%, but the item dosen't resize to fit the content . The same scenario works well for horizontal and vertical layout.Is there any solution???..

My code looks like this

```
<s:List width="{this.width}" dataProvider="{allActionsArrList}">
 <s:layout>
  <s:TileLayout />
 </s:layout>
 <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
     <s:ItemRenderer width="100%" height="40">
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%">
    <s:Label text="{data.name}" />

    </s:BorderContainer>
      </s:ItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
   <s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your aim? Do you want to have single column tile layout or you want to remove gaps between cells? Please describe what you're expected.

Comment: Actually its not single column,I may have many items in tile layout.My expectation is it should occupy the entire size of the list.My item does not have fixed width,it is 100%.So if there are two items in the list,those two items should occupy the entire list space.

Comment: The items have a minWidth value,so only when the size is below the min width the items should start in a new row.I hope its clear for you now.Thanks for replying...

Comment: Maybe you need some kind of flow layout described here http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/horizontal-multiline-layout/ or here http://evtimmy.com/2009/06/flowlayout-a-spark-custom-layout-example/ ?

Comment: That did not help.Is there anything to do with useVirtualLayout?.

Answer (score 5):

Trying adding this to TileLayout:

```
TileLayout columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth"
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, here is my I understanding of what you want to do:

You need the items in a List to evenly stretch horizontally occupying 100% width of the List. So if there's only 1 item, it occupies 100% width of the List. If there's an item too many (i.e. all items must be resized below their minWidth), the last item is moved to the next row.

Here's what you can achieve with TileLayout:

You can set `columnWidth="{yourItemRendererMinWidth}"` and `columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth"`. This makes your TileLayout divide its rows evenly into columns with minimum width as yourItemRendererMinWidth. If a column exceeds List container's right edge, it is transferred to the next row, while all the previous columns in the row stretch to container's right edge.

However, there will be empty columns on the row (e.g. if there're 2 items with minWidth=100, and your List's width is 300, there will be one empty column). You'll have to programmatically adjust `columnWidth` or `requestedColumnCount` on your TileLayout if you have too few items.